# Can anyone help me understand how to implement a karnaugh map using multiplexers in logism?

Tags: multiplexer, karnaugh-map

I am quite confused on how to implement a function using multiplexers. I know how to use a karnaugh map and get the necessary minimized function that I need, but I don't know how to implement it in logism using muxes.

For example, if I were to get the following function:

f = \$\Sigma\$ (6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)

The answer would be A!C + A!B + BC!D.

However, how does that translate in logism? what would the select bits be? And how would you use the 4 inputs A,B,C,D? Would you have to use multiple muxes, or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 16:1 multiplexer where A,B,C and D are the address lines and you set the appropriate (1 to 16) input lines to either 1 or 0 to get your required output. The minimal result from the karnaugh map doesn’t really help if you are going to use a multiplexer. This is the most useful formula in your question to aid you: -

> f = Σ(6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I sort of get it now. I was overthinking which made me confused on how to do things.